# Installing Discourse, after creating admin the website turns blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While installing Discourse from source I successfully got to the point of displaying my site. After adding admin with “RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake user:create” the website went blank, white screen. Does anyone know how to fix this? There does not seem to be action for removing admin..

Also, I am trying to install it in production but noticed it shows development environment when starting (see below), could this be relevant?

```
supp@mrde:/var/www/html/discourse$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec pumactl -P /var/www/html/discourse/tmp/pids/puma.pid start
[8759] Puma starting in cluster mode…
[8759] * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
[8759] * Min threads: 8, max threads: 32
[8759] * Environment: development
[8759] * Process workers: 4
[8759] * Preloading application
[8759] * Listening on unix:///var/www/html/discourse/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
[8759] ! WARNING: Detected 3 Thread(s) started in app boot:
[8759] ! # – /var/www/html/discourse/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/hiredis-0.6.3/lib/hiredis/ext/connection.rb:19:in `read’
[8759] ! # – /var/www/html/discourse/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/message_bus-2.2.0/lib/message_bus/timer_thread.rb:123:in `sleep’
[8759] ! # – /var/www/html/discourse/lib/discourse.rb:619:in `sleep’
[8759] * Daemonizing…
```

Comment: Not to discourage you, but you'll probably have better luck getting an answer posting on their own forum. https://meta.discourse.org/

Comment: You are right. It looks like I have solved this. After inspecting the site in the Chrome I noticed some js assets were missing. I then saw it that one file had an under slash added to the front. So I renamed public/assets/_vendor-25f91d66eba869fbd399d751711e74544b6d60bf034a5350b61c6c12caad0e2a.js to public/assets/vendor-25f91d66eba869fbd399d751711e74544b6d60bf034a5350b61c6c12caad0e2a.js and it started working. I just wish I know why this happened.